# print 10 lists of 100 randomnumbers range(1,100) and also each number repeats in the same list but not in another list using python?

Tags: python

```py
import random

n=int(input("Enter the range:"))

n1=int(input("Enter the range for randint:"))

n2=int(input("Enter the range for randint:"))

temp = 0

while True:

    list_1=[]

    for j in range(n):
        r = random.randint(n1,n2)

        if  r   list_1 :
            list_1.append(r)

    print('Randomised list is: ',list_1)

    temp+=1
    if temp == 10:
       break
```

Comment: Hi manoj, consider editing your question to make it clear what you want to achieve. Now it's rather hard to figure it out. Also, I see that you've commented under both answers that you expected a different result - this further suggests that your question does not contain enough details, or is unclear.

Comment: Please try to improve your question. You can add text with a better explanation of what do you want, and format the code appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import random
lists = []

for i in range(10):
    numbers = list(range(1,100)) #A list of numbers to choose from

    ## select 100 numbers from our remaining numbers
    next_list = [random.choice(numbers) for i in range(100)]
    lists.append(next_list)

    ## subtract used numbers from our list of choices
    numbers = list(set(numbers) - set(next_list))
print(lists)
```

Comment: thanks but not the result i wanted could you try another one ...it has print 10 different lists in a range of (1,100) i was close i had got 10 lists but the numbers are inter linked from one list to another ..their should not be any link from one list to another .

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to do, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're trying to achieve. A `10x10` of random numbers that doesn't repeat.

Try the following:

```
import random

list_of_random_lists = []
current_random_list = []
curr_random_number = -1
used_numbers = []

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        curr_random_number = random.randint(1,100)
        while curr_random_number in used_numbers:
            curr_random_number = random.randint(1,100)
        current_random_list.append(curr_random_number)
        used_numbers.append(curr_random_number)
    list_of_random_lists.append(current_random_list)
    current_random_list = []
    
for random_list in list_of_random_lists:
    print(random_list)
```

Let me know if this helps.